# Where to use the HDFS data in Web UI - MapR

Tags: hadoop, mapr

I am able  to connect to Mapr Control System - MCS - port 8080  (Web - UI) but where can i see the data file i copied from my local files system.??

On the MCS Navigation Pane , I can  see the below tabs but i dont see where to  navigate to data folder.

```
**Cluster
   Dashboard
   Nodes
   Node Heatmap
   Jobs
MapR-FS
  MapR Tables
  Volumes
  Mirror Volumes
  USer Disk USage
  Snapshot
NFS HA
 NFS Setup
Alarms
...
...
..
system Settings
-..
..
..
HBASE
...
Resource Manager
Job History Server
..**




**Hadoop Command:** 


]$ hadoop fs -ls -R /user
drwxr-xr-x   - mapr mapr          1 2019-06-25 12:47 /user/hive
drwxrwxr-x   - mapr mapr          0 2019-06-25 12:47 /user/hive/warehouse
drwxrwxrwx   - mapr mapr          6 2019-06-26 11:34 /user/mapr
drwxr-xr-x   - mapr mapr          0 2019-06-25 12:14 /user/mapr/.sparkStaging
drwxr-xr-x   - mapr mapr          0 2019-06-24 15:40 /user/mapr/hadoop
drwxrwxrwx   - mapr mapr          1 2019-06-26 11:48 /user/mapr/rajesh
-rwxr-xr-x   3 webload webload        219 2019-06-26 11:48 /user/mapr/rajesh/sample.txt
-rwxr-xr-x   3 mapr    mapr           219 2019-06-25 13:46 /user/mapr/sample.txt
drwxr-xr-x   - mapr    mapr             0 2019-06-25 12:14 /user/mapr/spark-warehouse
drwxr-xr-x   - mapr    mapr             1 2019-06-24 13:37 /user/mapr/tmp
drwxrwxrwx   - mapr    mapr             0 2019-06-24 13:37 /user/mapr/tmp/hive
```

Comment: MapR Fs - Volumes?